# Translate a word in frontend

Tags: magento-1, localisation

I have an extension: cmsmart extension search ajax and in the search I need to translate: "All categories". I tried this but its not working:

[image]

1. Add the translation into
   `app/design/frontend/default/MI_THEME/locale/es_ES/translate.csv`
2. Translate in line. This word not appear with a red border.
3. In admin configuration.

What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

1. I’ll recommend you to ask the developer of the cmsmart module for support.
2. If you are having issues contacting the support, I can suggest you the following:

Probably, this line wasn’t got through the helpers’ translator (`__()` method) and that was the reason why it didn’t translate correctly. Try to find the block or template, where it is shown and look how it displayed. If the value is transmitted directly, you should modify the inference by adding the translator (use the original helpers’ module). Then, open the file with translations of your module and fill it out. The translation should now work correctly.

Comment: I tried that, I search in the block and template but I don't know where is that. It is the first time this happens this to me. The "All categories" doesn't appear in all the code because I search it with "grep". So.. This have to appear with other way..I'll keep looking until the support answer me. Thanks for everthing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` translate feature instead.

Check this links :

- [Magento :: Translate text from javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751094/magento-translate-text-from-javascript-files)
- [3 ways to Add JavaScript Translations in Magento](http://www.webspeaks.in/2013/10/3-ways-to-add-javascript-translations-in-magento.html)

Hope this helps